# Evaluating models on the entire training set with no cross-validation

Tags: machine-learning, cross-validation

We have a dataset with 10,000 manually labeled instances, and a classifier that was trained on all of this data.
The classifier was then evaluated on ALL of this data to obtain a 95% success rate.

What exactly is wrong with this approach? Is it just that the statistic 95% is not very informative in this setup? Can there still be some value in this 95% number? While I understand that, theoretically, it is not a good idea, I don't have enough experience in this area to be sure by myself. Also note that I have neither built nor evaluated the classifier in question.

Common sense aside, could someone give me a very solid, authoritative reference, saying that this setup is somehow wrong?

For example, [this page](http://www.saedsayad.com/model_evaluation.htm) does say

> Evaluating model performance with the data used for training is not acceptable in data mining because it can easily generate overoptimistic and overfitted models.

However, this is hardly an authoritative reference. In fact, this quote is plainly wrong, as the evaluation has nothing to do with generating overfitted models. It could generate overoptimistic data scientists who would choose the wrong model, but a particular evaluation strategy does not have anything to do with overfitting models per se.

Comment: Don't you think that this question is for CrossValidated? http://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The fact of having `95%success rate` on the training set gives you no information about the quality of your model when you use it on real data. Imagine you have no contradicting instances (two equivalent instances, that have a different label). You can then write a model which just memorizes the labels for each instance and you get 100% correct predictions. You will agree that this model probably will perform horribly on real data.

Comment: Asked on CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/why-not-validate-on-the-entire-training-set

Comment: @cel, I also think this way, but I can find no solid way to justify this opinion beyond saying that "many people on the internet seem to think this way".

Comment: I asked it on CrossValidated: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/130985/why-not-validate-on-the-entire-training-set   Feel free to close.

Comment: @osa well, it's data science. If you are looking for a formal prove, maybe someone from stats knows one. I myself don't need a formal proof for things that are intuitively clear. I mean, you can just simulate the data, create an overfitting model, predict on a simulated test set and see how it fails horribly.
And the quote you have in your question just says, that for exactly that reason you can and should not evaluate on the training set alone. I don't see any problems with the quote :)

Comment: @cel, how would you convince someone else that evaluating on a training set is not O.K. if they are relying on expert opinion that it is O.K., it is just not "proper cross-validation" ? That's why I was hoping for a reference in something authoritative.

Comment: @osa, well `what` is authorative for you? Some famous scientist, who says so? A textbook that states this? A counter example that shows, that `training` error and `test` error can be completely different? A formal prove?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the possibility of [overfitting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting). That does not mean that there is no value in the accuracy you reported for that entire data set, as it can be considered an estimate of the upper bound for the performance of the classifier on new data.

It is subjective to say who constitutes a "very solid, authoritative reference"; however *Machine Learning* by Tom Mitchell (ISBN 978-0070428072) is a widely read and oft-cited text that discusses the problem of overfitting in general and specifically with regard to decision trees and artificial neural networks. In addition to discussion of overfitting, the text also discusses various approaches to the *training and validation set* approach (e.g., cross-validation).

Comment: The question is to find a reference.